# Setting iPhone wallpaper (locked screen background) programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, native, wallpaper

I have an app which could benefit from the user being able to choose to set an image as the wallpaper (the background image on the "slide to unlock" screen).

Is there a way for non-jailbreak third-party apps to do this? A search for "wallpaper" in the iPhone documentation returns nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to do this with the current SDK, if you want to do it you should file a [bug](http://bugreporter.apple.com).

Answer (score 6):

If you're writing a jailbreak application you can write to `/var/mobile/Library/LockBackground.jpg` and then kill the Springboard.