# Setting The Wallpaper On An IPad

Tags: ipad, iphone-sdk-3.2

I think there is no way to set the lock screen wallpaper on the iPhone programmatically (with ref to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248982/setting-iphone-wallpaper-locked-screen-background-programmatically)), but with the 3.2 SDK and the ability to set the wallpaper on the home screen on the iPad, does the SDK allow this to be done via APIs now?

I looked up the developer reference, but i could not find anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a method for that. The user can change it in the settings. But if you could change it progmatically, I'm sure there would be a lot of people who would abuse it...

Comment: Android allows this. Given that every iPhone app is reviewed for potential abuse, you would think iOS would have an API. One more app I can't write for the iPhone.

Comment: You are right. Android allows this. In my opinion both of the operating systems have their advantages...

Comment: Yes if you consider not being able to do something an 'advantage'