# How to change wallpaper in iPad programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ipad

How to change wallpaper in iPad programmatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612160/setting-the-wallpaper-on-an-ipad

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do this. The user decides what wall paper s/he wants and has one, single place to change it. You can, however, add new items to the user's saved photos list, which they can choose from when they change their wallpaper.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it is possible: see this link:

[You can save pictures to your iPad's photo album or directly to wallpaper -- a neat feature.](http://www.businessinsider.com/tron-iad-2010-12#you-can-save-pictures-to-your-ipads-photo-album-or-directly-to-wallpaper-a-neat-feature-17)

Quite likely, it's a private api, that only Apple can use in their iAds, but I'm still interested in how they accomplish that.

As far as I know, iAds are basically just little HTML5 web sites, so, the call would be part of the html code. It shouldn't be to difficult to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Interesting. Hope they open up this API developers.

Comment: Sjakelien - You didn't get the question - the key word is "PROGRAMMATICALLY" dah....  Thanks for posting your answer anyway.

Comment: Apparently, iAds is already discontinued nowadays. Has anyone managed to reverse engineer the Save Wallpaper call back in the days?