# how to set image as background programmatically,iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

HI all, 
how to set an image as a wallpaper, programmatically, in iphone?

Suggestions are always appreciated.
regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change wallpaper in iPad programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649529/how-to-change-wallpaper-in-ipad-programmatically) (same OS, same resolution.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i got the answer here

http://tiptopobjectivec.blogspot.com/2010/06/change-wallpaper-programatically.html

setting wallpaper progrmmatically, is undocumented API. so cant use.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about changing the phone's wallpaper, that's not possible programmatically.