# iPhone/iPad wallpaper image monotouch

Tags: ios, ios5, xamarin.ios

is there a way to setup an image as a device wallpaper? Originally I want to download an image, save it somewhere in a picture roll and set it up as a wallpaper programmatically.

google doesn't give me any answer on how could it be done.

Comment: ok, I didn't specify I want to do it from my app. does it sound like _programming_ question now?

Comment: Is this for jailbroken devices? If not, this isn't possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change wallpaper in iPad programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649529/how-to-change-wallpaper-in-ipad-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this API is not exposed to developers. There is also no URL scheme exposed for developers to launch the Photos app.

You're only option is to display a prompt that tells the user to manually go to the Photos application to set their wallpaper, and indicate how they would set the wallpaper there.