# set video or photo as iphone wallpaper xcode iphone programmatically

Tags: iphone, video, set, image, wallpaper

I want to set picture or video as a wallpaper on iphone from within the app.
Also is it possible that video runs on home sceen while iphone shows a grid of apps installed.i saw the same functionality in Android phone they have api that allow thhem to set wallpaper a pic or video

Comment: I believe setting wallpaper can only be done by the user. Do you want to add an action sheet to your app that will prompt the user to set a photo as wallpaper?

Answer (score 2):

You cant do this. There is no API available. Refer Stack Overflow question [How to change wallpaper in iPad programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649529/how-to-change-wallpaper-in-ipad-programmatically)