# Is it possible to change the Iphone background image directly from my app

Tags: ios, swift

In my app i would like (with the user permission) to change their iphone background image. Is it possible? If yes i would like some answer in Swift

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change wallpaper in iPad programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649529/how-to-change-wallpaper-in-ipad-programmatically). This question is 4 years old but the answer is the same. No you can't. And most likely you will never be able to do that with the official SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do it is to save the image to the camera roll, so the user can then set it as a background himself.