# How to change the system wallpaper/background of an iOS device with Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm curious if its possible to change the system wallpaper/background for an iOS device programmatically from your own application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting The Wallpaper On An IPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612160/setting-the-wallpaper-on-an-ipad)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change wallpaper in iPad programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649529/how-to-change-wallpaper-in-ipad-programmatically)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple doesn't provide a public API for doing this. The user must select the picture to use as the wallpaper via the Settings app.

You can make your app save pictures to the user's saved photos, and instruct the user to change the wallpaper manually.

Comment: Thank God this is not possible. :)

Comment: It should be possible. Point and case http://satelliteeyes.tomtaylor.co.uk/?ref=producthunt

Comment: @TylerBuchea that's a Mac app, not an iOS app.

Comment: That's the point. It's a good use case especially for a phone. @Greg and I are going to start a hate group until Apple gives us this API.

Comment: ^That awkward moment when you dont realize you *are* talking to Greg. XD