# How to set an image in my own app as wallpaper of lock screen in ios7？

Tags: ios, objective-c, wallpaper

I am building an album app. I want to set a photo in my own app as wallpaper. Is there some method available for doing so?

update:
I know there are already some similar questions posted. But they are out of time. So I am wondering if there is some method in iOS7 to implement so.

Comment: I think you cannot, please see this link [How to change wallpaper in iPad programmatically][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612160/setting-the-wallpaper-on-an-ipad

Comment: Not if you are planning to distribute your app on the App Store. Best you can do is save the image in to the camera roll and let the user set the wallpaper manually.

Comment: But there are many apps(especially wallpapers app)implementing so, how do they do?

Comment: I don't recall ever seeing an app that would directly set an image to your wallpaper. Maybe I'm wrong, but most wallpapers app just save the image to your camera roll.

Comment: You may want to download the image to the camera roll (see https://github.com/driftyco/cordova-camera-roll ) then let the user set it manually.

Answer (score 4):

For apps going into the app store this isn't possible. Apps can't change anything outside of their environment this is because apps on iOS run in a sandboxed mode so they don't know anything about other apps that are on the device and can't affect the OS directly.

To actually do it you would probably need to use some private API so your app would get rejected under:

> 2.5 Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected

but I suspect that they would actually reject it under:

> 10.4 Apps that create alternate desktop/home screen environments or simulate multi-App widget experiences will be rejected

As you are directly altering the home screen.