# How to set image as a background image in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have question that how could I set the ImageView image object as a background in my iPhone I use sdk 4.2 and in iPhone 4 its possible to set the backgound image in iPhone... So my case is that if some one likes the picture then they should give the UIAlertView to set as a background... OK & Cancel option in ok option its automatically set the image as a background.

My object are as follow:

```
UIImageView *imgViewObj = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageWithName:@"sampleImage.png"]];
```

I have to set this imgView obj as a background image...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot programatically set a user's wallpaper in iOS (yet anyway). You can probably do it on JB devices though, but that won't get you on the Apple appstore.

Comment: means its not possible ... and legal iphone 4 devices and its also mean that apple didn't accept those app

Comment: thanks i got it and i said to my client that no its not possible because client presure me to set the background .. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the iPhone background while you are outside of the app this is a repeat question. Otherwise in your own application just set contents of your root views layer to the CGImage you wish.

[Setting iPhone wallpaper (locked screen background) programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248982/setting-iphone-wallpaper-locked-screen-background-programmatically)

[How to set iPhone Wallpaper Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214372/how-to-set-iphone-wallpaper-programmatically)

[change wallpaper via iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057885/change-wallpaper-via-iphone-app)

[How to change wallpaper in iPad programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649529/how-to-change-wallpaper-in-ipad-programmatically)